# What type of distribution is this?

Tags: distributions, density-function, histogram

What kind of distribution is the one reported here below?

[image: histogram of the density]

Comment: Stata users will recognise a Stata graph, irrelevant here except to advise that you can and should post Stata graphs as `.png` files.

Comment: It would be nice to have a sample size. By the look I think $n$ is at least 684.

Answer (score 10):

That is what real data looks like: messy and not fitting exactly one of the theoretical distributions. Whether or not that is a problem depends on what you want to do with it. One thing that I would keep an eye on is that there appears to be a hard lower bound, that seems to affect a noticeable part of your sample.

Comment: (+1) BTW I like the term "brand-name distribution", coined, I think, by Charles Geyer.

Comment: I learned that term from a previous post here by @Scortchi and have been slipping it into conversations ever since.

Comment: In thinking about the lower bound, note that $100 \ln(0.01)$ is about $-461$ and $100 \ln(0.02)$ is about $-391$. Conversely $\exp(-4.234309)$ is about $.0145$ and I have no story there.